# Descending sorting LDAP with Spring Boot

Tags: java, sorting, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap

Is it possible to sort records from LDAP directory with SortControlDirContextProcessor descending, not ascending?

I based on this:
[SpringLdap - LdapTemplateSortedSearchITest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/core/src/itest-openldap/java/org/springframework/ldap/control/LdapTemplateSortedSearchITest.java)

```
public void testSearch_SortControl_ConvenienceMethod() {
    SortControlDirContextProcessor requestControl;

    // Prepare for first search
    requestControl = new SortControlDirContextProcessor("cn");
    tested.search(BASE, FILTER_STRING, searchControls, callbackHandler,
            requestControl);
    int resultCode = requestControl.getResultCode();
    boolean sorted = requestControl.isSorted();
    assertThat("Search result should have been sorted: " + resultCode, sorted).isTrue();
    List list = callbackHandler.getList();
    assertSortedList(list);
}
```

It works but ascending. How to set descending sort?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it could be helpful:

**public SortKey(String attrID,
               boolean ascendingOrder,
               String matchingRuleID)**

Creates a sort key for an attribute. Entries will be sorted according to the specified attribute in the specified sort order and using the specified matching rule, if supplied.

**Parameters:**
**attrID** - The non-null ID of the attribute to be used as a sort key.

---

**ascendingOrder** - *If true then entries are arranged in ascending order. Otherwise there are arranged in descending order.*

---

**matchingRuleID** - The possibly null ID of the matching rule to use to order the attribute values. If not specified then the ordering matching rule defined for the sort key attribute is used.

It is from docs: [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/SortKey.html)

Regarding your question: [Example code from java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/sort.html)

And I found one more alternative called **unboundid ldap sdk**
[link](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/controls/ServerSideSortRequestControl.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you @Echoinacup please explain where am i supposed to init sortkey? SortControlDirContextProcessor as parameter consumes String, not SortKey.

Comment: ok examples are fine, but it seems to not work with Spring Boot, what i am asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to implement a custom *DirContextProcessor* that allowed me to sort on multiple attributes with the desired direction (ascending/descending) by making use of the overload method of the *SortControl* class that takes an array of *SortKey*s objects as a parameter.

The implementation must extend the [*AbstractFallbackRequestAndResponseControlDirContextProcessor*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ldap/control/AbstractFallbackRequestAndResponseControlDirContextProcessor.java) and override the *createRequestControl* method.

The superclass *AbstractFallbackRequestAndResponseControlDirContextProcessor* will take care of the actual creation of the control. It only expects 2 pieces of information from the subclass.

1. The fully qualified class name of the control to instantiate
2. The types and values of the constructor parameters

The fully qualified class name is provided in the subclass property *defaultRequestControl*, and the types and values of the constructor parameters are provided in the subclass method *createRequestControl*.

The information of the sorting direction for any particular attribute is provided in the *ascendingOrder* property of the *SortKey* object.

```
public class SortMultipleControlDirContextProcessor extends AbstractFallbackRequestAndResponseControlDirContextProcessor{

    private SortKey[] sortKeys;
    private boolean sorted;
    private int resultCode;

    public SortMultipleControlDirContextProcessor(SortKey ... sortKeys){

        if(ArrayUtils.isEmpty(sortKeys)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("At least one key to sort on must be provided.");
        }

        this.sortKeys = sortKeys;
        this.sorted = false;
        this.resultCode = -1;
        this.defaultRequestControl = "javax.naming.ldap.SortControl";
        this.defaultResponseControl = "javax.naming.ldap.SortResponseControl";
        this.fallbackRequestControl = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.ctl.SortControl";
        this.fallbackResponseControl = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.ctl.SortResponseControl";

        loadControlClasses();
    }

    @Override
    public Control createRequestControl(){
        return super.createRequestControl(new Class[]{SortKey[].class,  boolean.class}, new Object[]{sortKeys, critical});
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleResponse(Object control) {

        Boolean result = (Boolean) invokeMethod("isSorted", responseControlClass, control);
        this.sorted = result;

        Integer code = (Integer) invokeMethod("getResultCode", responseControlClass, control);
        this.resultCode = code;
    }

    public SortKey[] getSortKeys(){
        return sortKeys;
    }

    public boolean isSorted(){
        return sorted;
    }

    public int getResultCode(){
        return resultCode;
    }
}
```

After the implementation, you can use the class to sort the results on multiple attributes in any desired direction:

```
// SortKey for sorting results on the cn attribute in descending order
SortKey cnSortKey = new SortKey("cn", false, null);

// Instantiate the control
SortMultipleControlDirContextProcessor myCustomControl = new SortMultipleControlDirContextProcessor(cnSortKey);

// Perform the search with the control
List<User> users = ldapTemplate.search("", orFilter.encode(), searchControls, new UserAttributesMapper(), myCustomControl);
```